# impossible to start adb - cannot debug Visual Studio 2015 Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Visual Studio 2015 provides a tool for hybrid app using Apache Cordova.
So I am trying my first app deploying it on an Android device.

I manage to deploy it on my device, but when I launch it I see two things:

1. on my device, the menu gets open up for a couple of seconds before my "hello world" starts
2. **on my PC I see a pop-up windows containing the below message**
3. I cannot debug because the connection between my PC and my device is dropped

***impossible to start PATH\adb.exe -  unknown error 0x80070057 -***

Please note that at PATH the file adb.exe is present.
my OS is Windows 8.1

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was mentioned again in a question posted to this site after yours:

[visual studio 2015 apache cordovo not running in emulator with Blank app project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221589/visual-studio-2015-apache-cordovo-not-running-in-emulator-with-blank-app-project)

The solution there was to re-install the Android SDK and try again.